# How do I center an IOS ScrollView on app startup?

Tags: ios, swift

When the app starts up, I want to display a 10x10 grid based on a ScrollView.  When the app loads, I get this:

[image]

... when what I really want to see is

[image]

Seems like it should be easy but I can't seem to Google the correct solution. Any suggestions?

Edit:  I am using SwiftUI.  Here's what my code looks like ATM:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TableView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let width = 0...10
        let height = 0...10
        
    NavigationView {
            ScrollView ([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
                VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                 ForEach (height, id: \.self) { h in
                        HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                            ForEach (width, id: \.self) { w in
                                
                                if (h == 5 && w == 5) {
                                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "X.png")!)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                               } else {
                                    Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Blank.png")!)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 1200, height: 1200, alignment: .center )
            }   // end ScrollView
            
        }
    }
    
}

struct TableView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TableView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using SwiftUI or UIKit? Also, can you show your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScrollView won't center itself by default — you'll need to add a [`ScrollViewReader`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader).

```
ScrollView ([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
    ScrollViewReader { proxy in /// here!
        VStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            ForEach (height, id: \.self) { h in
                HStack (alignment: .center, spacing: 0){
                    ForEach (width, id: \.self) { w in
                        
                        if (h == 5 && w == 5) {
                            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "X.png")!)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                            
                        } else {
                            Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "Blank.png")!)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 40, height: 40, alignment: .center)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            proxy.scrollTo(5) /// scroll to center
        }
    }
}
.frame(width: 1200, height: 1200, alignment: .center)
```

Result:

[image: Grid is centered]

Comment: Alas, now my scrollView is locked into place.  More reading required, I guess.